# Como puedo obtener registros de ventas por dias de la semana? Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: estructura de la tabla ventas]estoy queriendo hacer un grafico estadistico para un sistema de punto de ventas... y necesito obtener la cantidad de ventas realizadas de domingos a lunes... por ejemplo.. El lunes se vendio por 40$, el martes por 10$, miercoles por 60$ y asi sucesivamente... Es posible hacer esto solo con una sentencia sql..
MI  tabla tiene mas o menos esta estructura

```
Ventas
   id
   fecha_hora
   total
```

La verdad no tengo idea de como hacer una sentencia como la que quiero.. Basicamente lo que necesito es un ejemplo de como obtener datos ordenados por dias de la semana
Gracias de antemano

ACTUALIZACION...
Probe con esta sentencia que me trae los registros solo de la semana actual con sus dias..

```
SELECT total, DAYOFWEEK(fecha_hora) as dia FROM ventas WHERE YEARWEEK(`fecha_hora`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) ORDER BY `dia` ASC
```

[image: este es el resultado de la consulta]

Como puedo hacer para sumar los registros que corresponda al mismo dia? por ejemplo.. sumar todos los registros del dia 3, 4, 5 por separado

Comment: ¿`mysql` u `oracle`?

Comment: en mysql amigo.

Comment: La pregunta es confusa y esta incompleta. Debemos saber la estructura de tu tabla (no mas o menos, como te contestamos, con un sql mas o menos?) que es cada campo, un ejemplo de los datos y un ejemplo de la salida. y ademas, que intentaste y no funciono

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que te confunde... La tabla se llama ventas y tiene 3 columnas, el id, la fecha_hora en que se creo el registro y el total de la venta... Yo lo unico que estoy buscando es un ejemplo de como obtener esos registros ordenados por dias de la semana actual... por ejemplo que registro se creo el lunes, el martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes, sabado y domingo.. Saludos

Comment: Ordenar por dias de la semana, es lo mismo que ordenar por fecha, solo que empiezas con la que sabes que es lunes.. Por eso te pedia un ejemplo de datos. Mysql tiene funciones para saber que dia de la semana es determinada fecha.

Comment: acabo de agregar una imagen con la estructura de la tabla.. con eso podrias ayudarme? Saludos.

Comment: si. Mira esta es la funcion para obtener el [dia de la semana](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek). Con eso, ya tenes un punto de partida. Intenta algo, y si fallas, pone que intentaste y fallo y de ahi podemos ayudarte mas...

Comment: Estoy apunto de solucionar mi problema... solo que no se como puedo sumar los resultados del mismo dia

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imagenes con datos o con código fuente, publica directamente el texto del código y los datos como texto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el campo "total" signifca el total de dinero por ese día.

Podrías definir un campo que en vez de fecha_hora de tipo TIMESTAMPS, fuese dia_semana DATENAME y te genera al igual que TIMESTAMPS la hora en la que se introduce, en este caso, el día en el que se introduce una venta. Si no me equivoco, el valor del día lo introduce en inglés.

```
SELECT total FROM Ventas WHERE dia_semana LIKE 'Día de la semana que te interese';
```

`SELECT` para realizar una consulta a la tabla.

`total` el campo que queremos mostrar. (Cantidad de dinero)

`FROM Ventas` para seleccionar los datos de Total de qué tabla será.

`WHERE dia_semana LIKE` para establecer una condición, en este caso que el valor de `dia_semana` sea igual a un determinado día realizando la comparacion con `LIKE` al valor entre comillas simples.

Comment: Como seria lo del DATENAME? hay un tipo de dato con ese nombre o como seria? Saludos.

Comment: Guardar un campo con el nombre del dia, cuando se obtiene de una funcion, seria logico solamente si fuera un datawarehouse.. si no tendrias que hacer un trigger para guardar ese dato, o agregarlo a todos tus insert.. no se si seria algo muy conveniente...

Answer (score 0):

De la sentencia que tienes, ya que te interesan las ventas totales por día, te falta simplemente sumar y agrupar por día, algo como:

```
SELECT   DAYOFWEEK(fecha_hora) as dia
       , sum(total) as VentasDia
  FROM ventas 
 WHERE YEARWEEK(`fecha_hora`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
 group by DAYOFWEEK(fecha_hora)
 ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(fecha_hora)
```